# SQLAlchemy group_by SQLite vs PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, group-by, sqlalchemy

For the web app we are building we used SQLite for testing purposes. Recently we wanted to migrate to PostgreSQL. That's where the problems started:

We have this SQLAlchemy model (simplified)

```
class Entity(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    i_want_this = db.Column(db.String)
    some_value = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I want to group all `Entity`s by `some_value` which i did like this (simplified):

```
db.session.query(Entity, db.func.count()).group_by(Entity.some_value)
```

In SQLite this worked. In retrospect I see that it does not make sense but SQLite did make sense of it. I can't say for sure which of the entities was returned.

Now in PostgrSQL we get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "entity.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT entity.id AS entity_id, entity.i_want_this AS entity_not...
^
[SQL: 'SELECT entity.id AS entity_id, entity.i_want_this AS entity_i_want_this, count(*) AS count_1 \nFROM entity GROUP BY entity.some_value']
```

And that error totally makes sense.

**So my first question is: Why does SQLite allow this and how does it do it (what hidden aggregation is used)?**

**My second question is obvious: How would I do it with PostgreSQL?**

I'm actually only interested in the count and the first `i_want_this` value. So I could do this:

```
groups = db.session.query(db.func.min(Entity.id), db.func.count()).group_by(Entity.some_value)

[(Entity.query.get(id_), count) for id_, count in groups]
```

But I don't want these additional `get` queries.

So I want to select the first entity (The entity with the minimal id) and the number of entities grouped by `some_value` or the first `i_want_this` and the count grouped by `some_value`

**EDIT** to make it clear:

- I want to group by `some_value` (*Done*)
- I want to get the number of entities in each group (*Done*)
- I want to get the entity with the lowest `id` in each group (*Need help on this*)
- *Alternatively* I want to get the `i_want_this` value of the entity with the lowest `id` in each group (*Need help on this*)

Comment: SQLite returns a value from a random row in the group. But what do you mean with "first"? SQL tables are not ordered.

Comment: I meant the entity with the lowest id as seen in my last code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your first question, check the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset):

> Each expression in the result-set is then evaluated once for each
>   group of rows. If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is
>   evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, it is evaluated
>   against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group. If
>   there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set,
>   then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row.

Concerning the second question, you'll probably have to explain what you actually want to achieve, considering that your current query also in SQLite returns more or less random results.

EDIT:
To get the entities with minimum id per group, you can use the `Query.select_from` construct:

```
import sqlalchemy.sql as sa_sql

# create the aggregate/grouped query
grouped = sa_sql.select([sa_sql.func.min(Entity.id).label('min_id')])\
                .group_by(Entity.some_value)\
                .alias('grouped')

# join it with the full entities table
joined = sa_sql.join(Entity, grouped, grouped.c.min_id == Entity.id)
# and let sqlalchemy pull the entities from this statement:
session.query(Entity).select_from(joined)
```

This will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT entities.id AS entities_id,
       entities.i_want_this AS entities_i_want_this,
       entities.some_value AS entities_some_value 
FROM entities JOIN (SELECT min(entities.id) AS min_id
                    FROM entities GROUP BY entities.some_value) AS grouped
ON grouped.min_id = entities.id
```